# how to Set item permission in sp2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am using SP 2013. i have a general list and a people group. I want all member in the group could create/modify/view all items and set special permission for each item.

```
What role should i grant to this group? i prefer to have a min permission.
```

can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The min role to just create/modify/view all items is **Contribute**. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels#default-permission-levels

To set item-level permission, click the ellipsis(...)  of the item -> Select Shared with -> Click Advanced -> Click Stop Inheriting Permissions in the ribbon -> Delete existing permissions you don't need -> Click Grant Permissions in the ribbon.

[image]

Comment: is Contribute able to set permission for items?

Comment: No, setting permissions for items needs full control permission level.